# Convex combination of independent random variables, that minimizes the $p$th moment

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization, expectation

> Suppose  $V$ and $W$ are independent. Let \begin{align} f(x)=E[
>  ((1-x)V+xW )^p] \end{align} for $x \in [0,1]$ and some even $p \ge 2$.
>   Find  \begin{align} \min_{0 \le x \le 1} f(x) \end{align}
>
> Also, suppose that $E[W^{2n+1}]=0$ for $2n+1 <p$, that is all odd
>   moments of $W$ are zero. (I think this should simplify this a little
>   bit)

Solution, to some of the cases can be done by expanding and taking the derivative.

Case of $p=2$
\begin{align}
E[ ((1-x)V+xW )^2]= (1-x)^2 E[V^2]+x^2 E[W^2]
\end{align} 
it is not difficult to check that the minimizing $x= \frac{E[V^2]}{E[V^2]+E[W^2]}$  and the minimum value is given by
\begin{align}
\min_{x\in [0,1]} f(x) =\frac{E[V^2]E[W^2]}{E[V^2]+E[W^2]}
\end{align}

Case of $p=4$

\begin{align}
E[ ((1-x)V+xW )^2]= (1-x)^4 E[V^4]+6x^2(1-x)^2E[V^2]E[W^2]+x^4 E[W^4]
\end{align}

and one must solve
\begin{align}
-4(1-x)^3 E[V^4]+6E[V^2]E[W^2] (2x-5x+x^3)+4x^3E[W^4]=0
\end{align}
which I guess can be done.

But this procedure becomes increasingly complicated.

**Are there any other techniques on how to approach this problem?
I also feel that this should have come up in some applications?**

**Here is also an example when the problem can be solve in general**

The problem can be solved if $V \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_v^2)$ and $V \sim \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_w^2)$. Since,
\begin{align} E[
 ((1-x)V+xW )^p] =E \left[(  \sqrt{(1-x)^2\sigma^2_V+x^2\sigma^2_W} Z )^p \right] = ((1-x)^2\sigma^2_V+x^2\sigma^2_W)^{p/2} E[Z^p]
\end{align} 
where $Z$ is standard norma. It is not difficult to check that the expression is minimized by  $x=\frac{\sigma_V^2}{\sigma_V^2+\sigma_W^2}$ (same as for $p=2$)

and we get that
\begin{align}
\min_{x \in [0,1]} f(x)= \frac{(\sigma_V^2\sigma_W^2)^{p/2}}{(\sigma_V^2+\sigma_W^2)^{p/2}} E[Z^p]
\end{align}

**Upper Bound**

We can derive the following upper bound on the problem by using value inspired optimal value for $p=2$ and triangle (Minkowski) inequality. We use $x=\frac{E^{2/p}[V^p]}{(E^{2/p}[V^p]+E^{2/p}[W^p])}$
\begin{align}
 \min_{x\in [0,1]} E[ ((1-x)*V+x W )^p ] &\le  \frac{ E \left[ (E^{2/p}[W^p] V +E^{2/p}[V^p] W )^p \right])}{ (E^{2/p}[W^p]+E^{2/p}[V^p])^p}  \\
&\le   \frac{ \left(E^{2/p}[W^p] E^{1/p}[V^p] +E^{2/p}[V^p] E^{1/p}[W^p] \right)^p }{ (E^{2/p}[W^p]+E^{2/p}[V^p])^p}\\
&= \frac{E[W^p]E[V^p] ( E^{1/p}[W^p]+E^{1/p}[W^p])^p}{(E^{2/p}[W^p]+E^{2/p} [V^p])^p}\\
& \le 2^p  \frac{E[W^p]E[V^p]}{(E^{2/p}[W^p]+E^{2/p} [V^p])^{p/2}}
\end{align}

Comment: You need to solve $E(((1-x)V+xW)^{p-1}(W-V))=0$ where all the terms with odd powers of $W$ will disappear. You'll get a polynomial in degree $p-1$ and I don't think there is anything simpler available unless you make some additional assumptions.

Comment: @A.S. I thought maybe there is some kind of functional analysis argument or using convolution some how. Anyway thanks