# Minimum of $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n { n \choose k} (1-x)^{n-k} x^k a_{n-k}b_k$ over $x \in [0,1] $

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, binomial-theorem

Given 
\begin{align}
f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n { n \choose k} (1-x)^{n-k} \cdot x^k \cdot a_{n-k} \cdot b_k
\end{align}

Find 
\begin{align}
\min _{x \in [0,1] } f(x)
\end{align}

We can assume that $a_k$ and $b_k$ are positive and monotone increasing sequences.

Note, that I am not interested in the minimizer $x^{*}$ but rather a minimum value of $f(x^{*})$.

**EDIT**

Based on the comments of A.S., we can redefine the problem:

Given

$$\begin{align}
g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n { n \choose k} (1-x)^{n-k} \cdot x^k \cdot c_k
\end{align}$$

for some $c_k>0$, find

$$\begin{align}
\min _{x \in [0,1] } g(x)
\end{align}$$

This problem is related to the question I posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668836/convex-combination-of-independent-random-variables-that-minimizes-the-pth-mom).

Comment: is $x \in [0,1]$ or is $x \in (0,1)$. If it's the latter then 0 is the minimum value which is achieved when $x = 0,1$.

Comment: @Michael Menke: Note that $0^0 = 1$.

Comment: ah, you are correct, i missed that it started at 0.

Comment: it is $b_k$ and not $b_n$, isn't it?

Comment: @Exodd Yes, thank you. Will correct.

Comment: The function seems to be convex, but I cannot see why.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I think so too. But even if it is convex. Do you think it is easy to find the minimum?

Comment: The problem is that I know very little about convex optimization and combinatorics. I am afraid you have to wait for another one. I was just interested.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp thanks for being interested. Click like

Comment: It looks like a hybrid between Bernoulli and Cauchy product. *Looks* easy, but I can't make sense of it right now.

Comment: @GyroGearloose Typo corrected. Thanks I will look the ideas about Bernoulli and Cauchy product. Please let me know we you have any other ideas.

Comment: Note that you can replace $a_{n-k}b_k$ by an arbitrary positive sequence $c_k$.

Comment: @ A.S. ok. Will add to the question.

Answer (score 3):

The function $g$ is a linear combination of Bernstein polynomials. As these polynomials are a basis of the space of polynomials, your question is equivalent to asking for the minimum value of an arbitrary polynomial of degree $n$, which is impossible to answer in this general form.

For Bernstein polynomials you can obtain upper and lower bounds of the function values from the coefficients $c_k$:
$$
\min_k c_k \le g(x) \le \max_k c_k \quad\forall x\in[0,1].
$$
The proof of this is simple:
$$
g(x) =\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}(1-x)^{n-k}x^kc_k
\le \max_k c_k \cdot \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}(1-x)^{n-k}x^k
= \max_k c_k \cdot 1,
$$
which also shows that the bound is sharp if the $c_k$'s are all of the same value.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will look into  Bernstein polynomials.   Are the bounds you propose the tightest on Bernstein polynomials?

Comment: The bound is sharp if the $c_k$ are all the same, then $g$ is constant.

Comment: Could your problem be casted as a problem on Bezier curves ?  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BezierCurve.html  For example with control points at $(k,c_k)$ or $(k,{n \choose k}c_k)$ in order to have a global "positive trend"

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the reference. Let me check.

Comment: @JeanMarie liked your approach. I read the through your reference. I am not sure if this can be done. Could you put some of your thoughts in an answer so we can discuss it?

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means an answer, but obviously more than a comment.

I have begun to make some trials with Matlab.

Here is my modest program with a graphical result.

`clear all;close all;hold on;
n=5;C=rand(1,n);
D=linspace(0,1,n);
E=C+i*D;plot(E,'color','r');
t=0:0.01:1;s=1-t;M=0;
for k=0:n-1;
    M=M+nchoosek(n-1,k)*(t.^k).*(s.^(n-1-k))*E(k+1);
end;
plot(M)`

I have assumed WLOG that all $c_k \in [0,1]$ but nothing else about the $c_k$s (the fact that this sequence is the product of two sequences, one increasing, the other decreasing seems to have a very moderate impact...). In red, the control "arm", with vertices the control points with coordinates $(c_k,k/n)$. Only the abscissas are interesting. In this case, the abscissa of the minimum abscissa of the (blue) curve is strongly influenced by $c_3$, the smallest of all $c_k$s.

[image]

Comment: what dies variable $i$ stand for?

Comment: It's the i of complex numbers (i^2=-1). It was slightly easier to work with complex numbers. But of course, all this can be written with two coordinates.